Coldsnap download disk.img not getting mounted on linux machine
I am trying to mount an image file which has been downloaded by coldsnap for a snapshot of AWS, but I am unable to mount it in Amazon Linux 2.
I Tried multiple commands as mount -o loop disk.img /mnt/disk, losetup -f disk.img && mount /dev/loop0 /mnt/disk but it's not working:
[root@ip-172-31-29-177 ec2-user]# mount -t ext4 /dev/loop0 /tmp/disk/

mount: /tmp/disk: wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock on /dev/loop0, missing codepage or helper program, or other error.

Can anyone please help me on this error?

do you know the image contains exactly one ext4 file system, no partition table? Otherwise, your mount -t ext4 makes no sense. Are you sure you've set up the image on loop devlce /dev/loop0? Make sure you understand what the commands you execute do!

How do I decide fs? How to know FS from that img file upon which I have created the loop device? Can you guide me pls?
